# How to fix RELEASE_SAFELY macro warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

in my class I define the following macro

```
#define RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER){[__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil;}
```

But I get this warning on that:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABMultiValueRef is a Core Foundation object which should be freed using CFRelease, not `-release`.

```
#define RELEASE_SAFELY_CF(X)  { CFRelease(X); X = NULL; }
```

If you don't want to create 2 macros, you could use a cast `[(id)__POINTER release]`. But I don't recommend this, as there is no rule saying all CFType can be sent Objective-C methods.

Answer (score 0):

## define RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER){[ (id) __POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil;}

add the "(id)" cast like the warning says.